# how to display an image from an array using raylib

Tags: c, raylib

I want to display a 28 x 28 grayscale image using raylib. I could not find documentation on how to do this from an array. Most examples show how to do this from a pre-formated image (png, jpeg, etc).

I looked at the [cheatsheet](https://www.raylib.com/cheatsheet/cheatsheet.html), but most of the examples are from files. The following is the minimal code required to reproduce my problem.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "raylib.h"

typedef struct Sample {
    int name;
    int *data;
} sample;

void show_sample(sample *smp) {

    int scH = 800;
    int scW = 450;

    InitWindow(scH, scW,"label");

    int index = 0;
    Color *pixels = (Color*)malloc(28 * 28 * sizeof(Color));

    for (int i = 0; i < 28 * 28; i++) {
        int c = (int) smp->data[index];
        Color grayscale = (Color){c, c, c};
        pixels[index] = grayscale;
        index++; 
    }

    Image img = {
        .data = pixels,
        .width = 28,
        .height = 28,
        .format = PIXELFORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED_R32G32B32,
        .mipmaps = 1};

     Texture2D texture = LoadTextureFromImage(img);
     UnloadImage(img);

     SetTargetFPS(60);

     while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
         BeginDrawing();
         ClearBackground(GRAY);
         DrawTexture(texture, scH / 2, scW / 2, GRAY);


         DrawText("this IS a texture loaded from an image!", 300, 370, 10, BLACK);


         EndDrawing();
      }

      CloseWindow();

      }

    
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  int data[]= {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,18,18,18,126,136,175,26,166,255,247,127,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,30,36,94,154,170,253,253,253,253,253,225,172,253,242,195,64,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,49,238,253,253,253,253,253,253,253,253,251,93,82,82,56,39,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,219,253,253,253,253,253,198,182,247,241,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,80,156,107,253,253,205,11,0,43,154,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14,1,154,253,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,139,253,190,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,190,253,70,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,35,241,225,160,108,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,81,240,253,253,119,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,45,186,253,253,150,27,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,93,252,253,187,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,249,253,249,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46,130,183,253,253,207,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,148,229,253,253,253,250,182,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,114,221,253,253,253,253,201,78,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,66,213,253,253,253,253,198,81,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,18,171,219,253,253,253,253,195,80,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,55,172,226,253,253,253,253,244,133,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,136,253,253,253,212,135,132,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  
  sample smp;
  smp.name= 5;
  smp.data = data;

  show_sample(&smp);
}
```

The text appears just fine, but the image/texture does now show up in the expected format. There appears to be some color pixels, but I want grayscale. My guess is that the format am using is incorrect.
I know this can be done in python but I don't want to use that. The array stored in smp looks as follows (obviously its an int array, the commas are here to distinguish the values):

it may look familiar because it is a 5 from the mnist database.

Comment: @Oka Thanks for the tip. I looked at it and I almost got it right. I thought that the PIXELFORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED_R32G32B32 format would work, but it doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [8-bit grayscale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale), the pixel format `PIXELFORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED_GRAYSCALE` can be used.

With this format, instead of `int data[]`, use `unsigned char data[]` to represent your image data.

(*Note that `UnloadImage(img);` is not required if `img.data` was not allocated with `malloc`, etc.*)

```
#include <raylib.h>

typedef struct Sample {
    int name;
    unsigned char *data;
} sample;

static void show_sample(sample *smp)
{
    int scW = 800;
    int scH = 450;

    InitWindow(scW, scH, TextFormat("label %d", smp->name));

    Image img = {
        .data = smp->data,
        .width = 28,
        .height = 28,
        .format = PIXELFORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED_GRAYSCALE,
        .mipmaps = 1
    };

    Texture2D texture = LoadTextureFromImage(img);

    SetTargetFPS(60);

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(DARKBLUE);
        DrawTexture(texture, scW / 2, scH / 2, WHITE);
        DrawText("This IS a texture loaded from raw image data!", 300, 370, 10, RAYWHITE);
        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char data[] = {
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3, 18, 18, 18,126,136,175, 26,166,255,247,127,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 30, 36, 94,154,170,253,253,253,253,253,225,172,253,242,195, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 49,238,253,253,253,253,253,253,253,253,251, 93, 82, 82, 56, 39,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 18,219,253,253,253,253,253,198,182,247,241,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 80,156,107,253,253,205, 11,  0, 43,154,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 14,  1,154,253, 90,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,139,253,190,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11,190,253, 70,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 35,241,225,160,108,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 81,240,253,253,119, 25,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 45,186,253,253,150, 27,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 16, 93,252,253,187,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,249,253,249, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 46,130,183,253,253,207,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 39,148,229,253,253,253,250,182,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 24,114,221,253,253,253,253,201, 78,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 23, 66,213,253,253,253,253,198, 81,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 18,171,219,253,253,253,253,195, 80,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0, 55,172,226,253,253,253,253,244,133, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,136,253,253,253,212,135,132, 16,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0
    };

    sample smp = { .name = 5, .data = data };

    show_sample(&smp);
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: raylib window]